# Laravel 4: path.base is empty on a Windows IIS 7.5 server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, path, bootstrapping

I have a bit of a hard time moving a Laravel 4 app on a Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS. The problem is that for a reason I cannot explain `$app['path.base']` (in `bootstrap/start.php`) is empty. In `bootstrap/paths.php` is set correctly to `'base' => __DIR__.'/..',` (I didn't change anything it's the default value), and the other paths `path.public` and `path.storage` are returning the correct values.

I cannot find if it is specific to IIS or anything on the subject.

EDIT: I notice `realpath(__DIR__.'/..')` returns nothing (false) on Windows/IIS ....

Thank you
fabien

Answer (score 0):

I got into some more troubles but updating PHP from 5.3.28 to 5.4.23 on Windows Plesk solved at least the `realpath` issue.